# ROW_NUMBER() for rows which consists of more rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
ObjectId|  Value
---------------------
    1   |   A
    1   |   A
    1   |   A
    5   |   B
    5   |   B
    5   |   B
```

ordered by value and try to get "row number" this way (one row consists from multiple rows):

```
RowNumber  |   ObjectId  |   Value
------------------------------------
    1      |      1      |     A
    1      |      1      |     A
    1      |      1      |     A
    2      |      5      |     B
    2      |      5      |     B
    2      |      5      |     B
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is the row number of EACH row. The function will never return the same number twice in the same partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `dense_rank`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by Value), ObjectId, Value
from thistable;
```

You can include two columns like this:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by ObjectId, Value), ObjectId, Value
from thistable;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's not ordered by ObjectId only, it can be ordered, by value (or other columns, which are same for one object). I edited sample

Comment: @DavidB. . . . Your edit doesn't change the logic, but if you want to include more columns in the `order by`, then you can.

Comment: I'm trying to do this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7cd6a/1 and it was the reason why it doesn't work. and it has no sense and solution, I will mark your Answer as correct, because it was first

Answer (score 0):

Look at `dense_rank()`, this will continue with the next number in sequence.  There's an [example here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/rank-vs-denserank-with-example-using.html).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8078e/3)

> Returns the rank of rows within the partition of a result set, without
>   any gaps in the ranking. The rank of a row is one plus the number of
>   distinct ranks that come before the row in question.

Comment: That's why I added `C` into the value to show the difference, you'll get 11, 22, 33 in the sample (the fiddle) if you order by value

Comment: thank you very much for your fiddle link, I didn't know this great tool

Comment: @DavidB. No problem, if it helped, you can mark the answer as helpful by upvoting, since someone downvoted :)

Comment: there's a -1 and a +1, that's fine.